# Applying CSS style conditionally in ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is my code.Am applying css for `if condition` and removing that css for `else condition` its working fine.
But I dont want to use 2 `<tr>` within one tr I need to achieve this and I dont want to use inine `css`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in userList"
   ng-if="data.appDate>=delivery.joinedDate"
   ng-style="{'background-color': '#ffd6d6','border':'dashed 3px #9e0b0f'}">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{data.name }}</td>
    <td>{{data.age}}</td>
    <td>{{data.dept}}</td>
    <td>{{data.appDate }}</td>
    <td>{{data.joinedDate}}</td>                         
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="data in userList" ng-if="!(data.appDate>=delivery.joinedDate)">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{data.name }}</td>
    <td>{{data.age}}</td>
    <td>{{data.dept}}</td>
    <td>{{data.appDate }}</td>
    <td>{{data.joinedDate}}</td>                         
</tr>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this using the [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive. You'll simply add your styling as a class in your stylesheet and change your angular code to this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in userList" 
    ng-class="{ 'my-css-class': data.appDate>=delivery.joinedDate }">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{data.name }}</td>
    <td>{{data.age}}</td>
    <td>{{data.dept}}</td>
    <td>{{data.appDate }}</td>
    <td>{{data.joinedDate}}</td>                         
</tr>
```

Stylesheet:

```
.my-css-class {
    background-color: #ffd6d6;
    border: dashed 3px #9e0b0f;
}
```

Comment: Css applies the most specific styles as the final, so one way is to make sure the class is the most specific - for instance classes directly targeting the element is always considered more specific than selectors targeting the parent class. It's tough to explain in a single SO comment, but I bet there are already questions related to this, under the CSS tag here on the site. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at ngClass.

You can dynamically set css based on a model.

[Angularjs ngClass docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

As a note, inline styling is not good practice.